# Upload Angular 4 Slim Framework 3

Tags: angular, slim3

Mas que una pregunta, lo quiero compartir ya que me dio un dolor de cabeza por varios días, quizás no es la mejor solución pero a mi me resulto.

ServiceUpload.ts

```
Upload_File(Files:any){
    var formData = new FormData();  
    formData.append("FileSize",Files.length);
    for(var i=0;i<Files.length;i++){
        formData.append("File-"+i,Files[i]);
    }
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'archivos/nuevo',formData).map(response =>response.json());
}
```

En mi controller.

```
$this->post('/nuevo', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $params = ($request->getParsedBody());
    $path = dirname( dirname(__DIR__) ) .'/uploads';
    $files = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    $data = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($files as $f){
        $filename = moveUploadedFile($path,$files['File-'.$i]);
        array_push($data, $filename);
        $i++;
    }
    $newResponse = $response->withJson($data, 201);
});
```